# Как вывести длину максимального элемента(типа str) из списка?

Tags: python, max

```
s = [i for i in input().split()]
print(max(s , key = len))
```

вводятся слова через пробел и добавляются в список и далее выводится максимальное по длине, но мне нужно чтобы выводилось ***длина*** этого максимального слова, а не само оно

пытался так , но ничего не получается:

```
print(max(len(s) , key = len))
```

пример работы см. ниже:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `print(len(max(s , key = len)))`

Comment: И полное решение в одну строку: ``print(len(max(input().split(), key=len)))``

Answer (score 5, accepted):

вариант 1 (наверное самый короткий по кол-ву используемых символов):

```
print(max(map(len, input().split())))
```

вариант 2:

```
print(max(len(i) for i in input().split()))
```

вариант 3:

```
print(len(max(input().split(), key=len)))
```

Answer (score 1):

попробуйте так:

```
s = [len(i)for i in input().split()]
print(max(s))
```

либо так:

```
print(max(len(i)for i in input().split()))
```